# C++ Optimizing for loops and if statements

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, optimization, filter

I am trying to optimize a filtering script which takes in a lot of lidar points (~175 million) and filters them according to whether they fall inside certain bounds (x min max, y min max, and z min max).

Right now the script iterates through each point, then through each boundary conditions (there are multiple bounds), and then tests in an if statement whether it falls within those bounds. (see code)

```
namespace filtering{
    std::vector<points_by_roof> filter_by_roof (std::vector<pointcloud::xyzfloats>& coordinates, const std::vector<roof_bounds>& bounds){
        //create filtered structure - roof_id, vector with all coordinates that will fall in that slice
        std::vector<points_by_roof> filtered (bounds.size());
        for (int i=0; i < bounds.size(); i++){
            filtered[i].id = bounds[i].id;
        }
        //Filtering points by roof slice
        for (int i=0; i < coordinates.size(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j < bounds.size(); j++){
                if (coordinates[i].z > bounds[j].z_range[0] && coordinates[i].z < bounds[j].z_range[1] &&
                    coordinates[i].x > bounds[j].x_range[0] && coordinates[i].x < bounds[j].x_range[1] &&
                    coordinates[i].y > bounds[j].y_range[0] && coordinates[i].y < bounds[j].y_range[1]){
                    
                    filtered[j].points.push_back({coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y, coordinates[i].z});

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

The code ran with 175 million points in about 20 seconds. Once I switched the if statement around to run the "z" bounds first it dropped to about 17 seconds.

I know of the if-statement optimization that C++ does where it changes:

```
if (a==b && c==d){}
```

to

```
if (a==b) {
    if (c==d){}
}
```

but I think changing the "z" bounds to be tested first is the only sure-fire example of that type of optimization. Is there a way to run this faster?

(it feels like the for loops are really hurting the timing but I am also fairly new to C++ so I may be incorrect)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :).

---

Edit:

I am sorry for the lack of code and specification, I see now that it is not very easy to help (I am new to C++).

For the comments below - There should be no points which fall in two boxes.

The overall project - read points in from a .las file (lidar point-cloud file), filter into boxes (define a section of a roof), and (for each box) fit to plane of best fit and compute the thickness of the roof.

Here are the data types that are being used:

in a namespace pointcloud (in point_cloud.h)

```
struct xyzfloats {
    float x, y, z;
    xyzfloats(float x_val, float y_val, float z_val) : x(x_val), y(y_val), z(z_val){}
};
```

in a namespace filtering (in filtering.h)

```
struct points_by_roof {
    std::string id;
    std::vector<pointcloud::xyzfloats> points;
};

struct roof_bounds {
    std::string id;
    int x_range[2], y_range[2], z_range[2];
};
```

I am fairly new to C++ and VERY new to C++ optimization, so any explanation on different datatypes or functions would (and their difference) would be helpful.

I can add more (or all) of my code if it would be helpful. I cannot (in response to a comment) upload a .las file to stack overflow.

Comment: Just to confirm, what flags are you passing the compiler? Did you remember to enabled optimization?

Comment: You want people to optimize code for a specific set of data without providing said data. It’s an impossible task even if someone were willing to optimize the code for you, if they don’t have the data necessary. Any suggestions are guesswork.

Comment: A minuscule optimization for you: Try buffering the output of those `size` function calls in variables. It may not be much, but having to call a function whose output will not change also costs cycles.

Comment: Also note: You can probably save a little work by using `filtered[j].points.emplace_back(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y, coordinates[i].z);` to directly construct the new point straight into the `vector`. That said, optimizing your code in general is hard here; you haven't given us definitions for most of your relevant classes, and if you omitted or misimplemented move construction/assignment, or default construction is super-expensive, or move construction/assignment is expensive so using `std::deque` over `std::vector` would save reallocation element move work, etc., we don't know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: That's unlikely to matter if optimizations are enabled; `bounds` is `const` so it should never change, and `coordinates` isn't changed, and most compilers should recognize the optimization opportunity. The OP could make it easier on the compiler by using for-each-style loops when possible, but modern compilers will optimize out even repeated `strlen` calls (which are legit `O(n)`); optimizing out `.size()` calls is a smaller savings (they're `O(1)`) and the compiler is usually smart enough to do it anyway.

Comment: This is data dependent. If I understand, you have multiple bounding cubes, but save a filtered point once. If the cubes don't overlap or if you don't care which cube a filtered point is listed under if it is in the intersection of cubes then you might order bounds by volume of cube. This is a (possibly invalid) heuristic that higher volume cubes will have more points, so may reduce average number of cubes that need to be checked for points that are in a result set.

Comment: Another potential data dependent possibility is to to calculate the bounding super cube to quickly eliminate some points that are in no cube. These possibilities are very data dependent & in some circumstances may slow things down rather than speed them up.

Comment: use `filtered.reserve` to allocate enough memory for all points and then trim it back to the actual size before returning. Should save a lot of copying if many points are included. Also try sorting your bounds to have the one with the most points in it first.

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? You include any point that is in at least one bounding box? You don't want points that are inside all bounding boxes?

Comment: @AviBerger yes that is correct - multiple bounding cubes, a point will only be in one bounding cube if any, but all of the bounding cubes should be roughly the same size. As for the super cube, the bounding cubes are kind of spread out (except for they are all relatively the same height, which is why I limited z first).

Comment: @ShadowRanger hopefully the edit adds the code that you were referencing, if there is something else I can certainly add it. I will definitely use the emplace function (my co-worker explained that one) but what is the difference between `std::deque` and `std::vector`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did not know there was an optimization built into C++ - that made it WAY faster. Dropped it down from 17.6 seconds to 2.16 seconds. Thank you :)

Comment: @ThomasK: `std::deque` allows efficient appends and pops from either end, and never copies or moves inserted items, in exchange for all accesses having a higher overhead (it's still `O(1)` element access, but it has to go through multiple levels of indirection on the way to each element, where `vector` is a single direct memory lookup). And yeah, without optimizations enabled (it's part of the compiler, not C++ itself), C++ is *much* slower, since all the layers of abstraction aren't removed (through inlining function calls, caching of logically constant values, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The way you write the `if` will have little to no importance. The compiler can deal with that.

The most obvious issue is the `push_back`. Make sure to `reserve` first, to prevent allocations.

Comment: *The way you write the if will have little to no importance.*  unless you can short-circuit singificantly more by reordering conditions, which seems to be the case in OP's data.

Comment: Given the size of each result doesn't look pre-computable, `reserve` doesn't seem like a real option. It might make sense to switch to `std::deque` (that never needs to move its contents); slightly higher fixed overhead for most operations than `std::vector`, but no object moves. Of course, for all we know, `.points` is a `std::deque` (the OP never specified).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Doesn't matter, produce your best guess at the size, and then reserve twice as much.